# How to save photos into a folder on google drive in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an app using IOS 8 in which I am saving photos to google drive. I have completed saving photos  and creating folder on google drive. but not able to save photos into folder on google drive.

Kindly help me to save photos into a folder on google drive.Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for creating folder

```
GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
    folder.title = @"xyz";
    folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    //folder.parents = @[parent];
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
    [self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                         GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                         NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Created folder");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

Here is the code for saving photos to google drive

```
GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
    file.title = datestring;
    file.descriptionProperty = @"Uploaded from the Google Drive iOS Quickstart";
    file.mimeType = @"image/png";

                       float actualHeight = image.size.height;


                       float actualWidth = image.size.width;

                       UIImage *myResizedImage ;
                       if (actualHeight>500 || actualWidth>500) {
                           myResizedImage = [ImageUtilities imageWithImage:image
                                                                   scaledToMaxWidth:300
                                                                          maxHeight:300];
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           myResizedImage=image;
                       }



    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)myResizedImage);



        GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:file.mimeType];

    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                                       uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
    GTLDriveParentReference *parentReference = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
    parentReference.identifier = @"root";
    file.parents = @[parentReference];


    NSLog(@"%@",query.q);
  //  UIAlertView *waitIndicator = [self showWaitIndicator:@"Uploading to Google Drive"];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.service executeQuery:query
                  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error)
     {
         //[waitIndicator dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
         if (error == nil)
         {


             NSMutableDictionary *value=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

             [value setValue:rowidstring forKey:@"rowid"];

             [value setValue:@"1" forKey:@"status"];
             NSLog(@"insertedFile.identifier %@",insertedFile.identifier);
             // [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"File saved!"];
             [value setValue:insertedFile.identifier  forKey:@"googleid"];
             [[sqlitedatabase shardclass]updateCustomerphotodata:value];






         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
             [self showAlert:@"Google Drive" message:@"Sorry, an error occurred!"];
         }
     }];
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Google Developers website [Working With Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/folders)

> To create a file inside a folder, set the parents property on the file
>   as shown in the below example:

**Create a folder inside a folder**

> By default, newly created files and folders are added to the root
>   folder. To create a folder inside a different folder, first retrieve
>   the parent folder to get its ID; then you can use that ID to set the
>   parents property on the new folder, as shown below:

```
GTLServiceDrive *drive = ...;
NSString *parentId = ...;

GTLDriveParentReference *parent = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
parent.identifier = parentId;

GTLDriveFile *folder = [GTLDriveFile object];
folder.title = @"My Application Files";
folder.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
folder.parents = @[parent];

GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folder uploadParameters:nil];
// ... execute query
```